How to interpret $L^2$ norm for functions from $[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^n$?
I have a function $\alpha \in L^2(0,T;A)$ where $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.
I understand what it means when $A= \mathbb{R}$, i.e.
$$\Bigg(\int_0^T|\alpha(t)|^2dt\Bigg)^{1/2}<\infty$$
If $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ $\alpha \in L^2(0,T;A)$ means that $$\Bigg(\int_0^T|\alpha_i(t)|^2dt\Bigg)^{1/2}<\infty \quad \forall i=1,\dots,n$$
where $\alpha(t)=(\alpha_1(t),\dots,\alpha_n(t))$?

$|x|$ is often used for the Euclidean norm of $x$ on $\mathbb R^{n}$.

In general, when you say that $\alpha \in L^2(0,T,A)$, this means that $$ \int_0^T \parallel \alpha(t)\parallel_A^2 dt < \infty $$
So, based on the norm defined on $A$, you can check whether the integral is well defined.
In particular, if $A \subseteq R^n$ you can choose the norm that you prefer since in finite dimentional spaces they are equivalent, so if you take as a norm the sum of the absolute value of every component, you get exactly what you have written.
